# template method pattern, where to define common used functions

Tags: ruby, templates, design-patterns

Thanks for your time!

I recently read about template pattern(in Ruby) and want to use this pattern in my codes.

My question is "where to put some commonly used functions".

Say I have TemplateRequestBody, JSONRequestBody and XMLRequestBody as following.

```
class TemplateRequestBody
  def pretty_format
    raised "called abstract method: pretty_format"
  end
end

class JSONRequestBody < TemplateRequestBody
  def pretty_format
    # pretty format JSON
    add_new_line_to_tail();
  end
end

class XMLRequestBody < TemplateRequestBody
  def pretty_format
    # pretty format XML
    escape_double_quotes();
    add_new_line_to_tail();
  end
end
```

In this example, `add_new_line_to_tail()` would be used by all child classes; `escape_double_quotes()` would be used only by some of the child classes.

Where should I implement these two functions? In TemplateRequestBody or?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of raising: `raise "called abstract method: pretty_format"`

You can use Ruby's built-in `NotImplementedError`: `raise NotImplementedError.new('pretty_format')`

Comment: Thanks @Ile Eftimov for this information！ I dont know this idea before. I'll look into that and implement in my codes.

Comment: Shameless plug: I've blogged about Ruby and Template method pattern, you can check it out [here](https://ieftimov.com/template-method-pattern-in-ruby) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it always is - it depends :)

If a method will be shared across subclasses, putting it in the parent class (`TemplateRequestBody`) would make sense. If the methods will not be shared across the subclasses, then don't put them.

If method is going to be used by *some* of the classes, maybe you could think if a mixin would be a good place to store that method? Also, putting it in the parent class won't be a terrible idea.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Fantastic blog! Thanks a lot :)